# Navigation bar does not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

It seems that I am doing something wrong, but I don't understand what. I have `UIViewController` and here is it's viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;

    // tableview initialisation

    // search bar initialisation

   menu = [[SINavigationMenuView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, 0, 200, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height) title:NSLocalizedString(@"ALBUMS", nil)];
   [menu displayMenuInView:self.view];
   menu.tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


   menu.items = @[NSLocalizedString(@"ALL", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"DOWNLOADS", nil), ...];

   menu.delegate = self.controller;
   self.navigationItem.titleView = menu;

   //sidebar button
   UIImage *sidebarButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"];
   UIButton * sidebarButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   sidebarButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, sidebarButtonImage.size.width, sidebarButtonImage.size.height);
   [sidebarButton setImage:sidebarButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [sidebarButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onMenuPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   UIBarButtonItem * leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sidebarButton];
   [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftButton];
}
```

After loading this view navigationBar does not appear.

Comment: This is not how you do this. Is this the root view controller of you application ? Are you using storybaords/xibs or are you doing it programatically ?

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];` What is that supposed to do ?

Comment: @CW0007007 I am doing it programmatically. It is not root view controller, but it is inside inside navigationController.viewcontrollers

Comment: IN that case it should inherit from it's parent view. How do you present this view ?

Comment: @Jkmn nothing, it left after experiments and attempts to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view controller must be inside of a navigation controller. Make sure your view controller is the root view or one of the view controllers in self.navigationController.viewcontrollers

If it is not contained inside of a navigation controller, you will have no bar.

Comment: You were right, I made this controller as root view controller, when I open appropriate view and that fixed the problem. Thanks